# Setting selected attribute to an option list that is tabulated dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, select, drop-down-menu

I have a set of options that are being tabulated dynamically.
**Eg: Below is a sample set of options that are being tabulated:**
option1
option2
option3

Here I am not explicitly setting any option as default and hence, by convention it is taking option1 as default.
However, what I want to do in my use case is search through the entire options and check if there is an option named **option3** and if it exists, then set it as default by adding the **selected=selected** attribute.

**Below is the code snippet of concern:**

**1. HTML**

```
<div class="form-grp">
    <label for="selectOption">Select Option</label>
    <select class="form-ctl" id="selectTemplate" data-field-type="option" class="tempList">                     
    </select>
</div>
```

**2. JS**

```
    var optionList = _.map(optObj, function(opt){
        return '<option>' + option.name + '</option>';
    });
 $('[data-field-type="option"]').html(optionList);
```

- Here, **optionList** is an object and I am fetching the option name from the object.

Can someone please help me with this.
I tried the following but with no luck.

```
var html = _.map(templates, function (template) {
  for(i=0;i<templates.length;i++){
      if(template.name=="story"){
          $( function() {
             $(".tempList option:selected").attr("selected", "selected");
          });
       }
   return '<option>'+ template.name + '</option>';
 }
});
```

Is it possible to do it without using the id selector?. Or is there any other way to simply loop through the options and then add the selected attribute to the option of interest?.

Thanks very much in advance. Any help or suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you want to set an option as selected by its content, so you can do it inside it like so:

```js
const optObj = [
  {name: "Option1"},
  {name: "Option2"},
  {name: "Option3"},
];

const optionList = optObj.map(function(option){
    return '<option>' + option.name + '</option>';
});

$('[data-field-type="option"]').html(optionList);
 
function selectOptionByContent(content) {
  $(`select option:contains("${content}")`).prop('selected',true);
}

selectOptionByContent("Option3");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-grp">
    <label for="selectOption">Select Option</label>
    <select class="form-ctl" id="selectTemplate" data-field-type="option" class="tempList">                     
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello @Saar,   Thanks for your quick response. The above solution works exactly how I want. Thanks again. Highly appreciated.